# Why pre-checked radio button cannot get value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on a simple project. But unfortunately my radio button cannot work perfectly when I press on submit button. Due to I am using show hide onclick function to disable hide element input text therefore I need to click on radio button first then only can work. What can I do to get "database" radio button id without click on any radio button?

This is HTML code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Send EDMs</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="confirm_sendemail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1" > 
Subject : <br/> 
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required/> <br/> 
Choose your upload type: <br /> 
<input type="radio" name="email" id="database" onclick="database_csv()" checked="checked" value="database"/>Database 
<input type="radio" name="email" id="csv" onclick="database_csv()" value="csv"/>CSV<br/> 
<div id="send_type" style="display:none"> 
    <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" accept=".csv" required/> <br/> 
</div> 
Content : <br/> 
<textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="10" required></textarea><br/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is javascript with onclick show hide function :

```
<script>
function database_csv(){    
  $('#send_type').hide().find('input').prop('disabled', true);
}
function csv_database(){
  $('#send_type').show().find('input').prop('disabled', false);
}

</script>
```

Comment: one issue - `<input type="radio" name="email" id="database"` see the name attribute

Comment: any problems on this ?

Comment: do this `$('input:radio[name=database]:checked').val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one "disable" code on your html input.

this is your code:

```
<input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" accept=".csv" required/>
```

replace your code like this :

```
<input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" accept=".csv" required disabled/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont get what you actually want but if you just want pre-checked radio button ID then you can try this

```
$("input:radio:checked").attr('id');
```

Or get a value using

```
$("input:radio:checked").val();
```

This is fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3wK7/)